Error failed to push some refs
Inicie clonan un repositorio que no tenia mas que un readme ese se supone que era mi problema pero aun asi iniciando otro repositorio yo donde si tenia todo tampoco me dejo hacer el push.Probé muchísimos comando y no encuentro una solución, probé desactivando el proxy de la red, cambiando el buffer y hasta forzando la subida. Dejo de referencia las imagenes del error.

Error de imagen 1:C:\Users\Belen\proyectoEcommerce\proyectoEcommerce>git push

fatal: protocol error: bad line length 183

send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ChrisChamizo/proyecto Ecommerce.git'

C:\Users\Belen\proyectoEcommerce\proyectoEcommerce>Enumerating objects: 1360, done.

Counting objects: 100% (1360/1360), done.

Delta compression using up to 2 threads

Compressing objects: 100% (1276/1276), done.

riting objects: 2% (28/1359)



Error de imagen 2:34-09-02 20:19:55.691 [warning] [Git][revParse] Unable to read file: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\Belen\proyectoEcommerce\proyectoEcommerce\_git\refs\remotes\origin\main

14-09-02 20:19:57.433 [info] > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main [1741ms]

20:19:58.853 [info] > git for-each-ref-format-%(refname)X8%(upstream: short)X80%(objectname)%(upstream: track)(upstream:resotename)(opstream:resoteref) --ignore-case rel

14-09-02 20:19:57.863 [info] > git status -z-uall [398ms]

2024-09-02 heads/main refs/remotes/main [925@s]

2024-09-02 20:19:59.112 [info] > git config --local branch.main.vscode-merge-base [160ws] 20:19:59.314 [info] > git for-each-ref-format-X(refname)X80%(upstream: short)e(objectname)X80%(upstream: track)(upstream:remotenase) Sock(upstream:romoteref) --ignore-case ref

heads/origin/main refs/remotes/origin/main [173as]

2024-09-02 C:\Users\Belen\proyectoEcommerce\proyectoEcommerce\public\css\Home.css [360us]

2024-09-02 20:20:07.332 [info] > git 1s-tree-1 17d748f88f5ce4de42f64ee1930ed075b612c87c [info] > git 1s-tree-1 6c81c3f29c0ce87c13d812b019e608aae331d3ee

2024-09-02 20:28:07.451 2024-09-02 20:28:07.538 [info] > git ls-tree-1 170748f88f5ce4de42f64ee1930ed875b612c87c

2824-09-02 20:20:07.569 [info] > git ls-tree-1 6c81c3f29c0ce87c13d012b019e608aae331d3ee

C:\Users\Belen\proyectoEcommerce\proyectoEcommerce\public\css\Wome.css [455ws]

C:\Users\Belen\proyectoEcommerce\proyecto.commerce\views\Hone.ejs [501as]

C:\Users\Belen proyectoEcommerce\proyectoEcommerce\views\ome.ejs [5130s



Ya te cerró previamente otra pregunta con un contenido casi idéntico. Sé descriptiva/o: muestra los mensajes de error y las salidas como texto, con formato, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Otros pueden ver las imágenes, pero son incómodas de leer, copiar y analizar.

Estas detras de un firewall corporativo?? suena a problema de red eso..

Probe intentando subir archivos a git desde una tablet  y si logre hacerlo,asi que si tiene que ser un problema entre git y gitlab en mi pc.Estoy en una red local de hogar
